# centrar una ventana de tkinter en el centro de la pantalla

Tags: python, tkinter

Buenas quiero saber si hay manera de abrir una ventana de tkinter (python) en el centro de la pantalla, ya he intentado muchas cosas que he encontrado pero no me funcionan, se posicionar mal o piede su forma, de antemano quiero saber como hacer esto.

este es un código de ejemplo del tamaño especifico de mi ventana

```py
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()
root.geometry("900x300")
root.resizable(0,0)
root.title("Ventana de ejemplo")


root.mainloop()
```

cuando ejecuto se muestra donde le da la gana

```py
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()
root.geometry("900x300+300+300")
root.resizable(0,0)
root.title("Ventana de ejemplo")


root.mainloop()
```

ya intente colocar 2 parámetros mas en el geometry pero no confió mucho en esas propiedades

Answer (score 2):

Debes aplicar la siguiente formula:

*mitad del tamaño de la pantalla menos la mitad del tamaño de la ventana tanto para el alto como el ancho y al final redondearlo.*

**redondear(largo_pantalla/2-largo_ventana/2)**

**redondear(ancho_pantalla/2-ancho_ventana/2)**

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()
root.geometry("900x300")
root.resizable(0,0)
root.title("Ventana de ejemplo")

#  Actualizamos todo el contenido de la ventana (la ventana pude crecer si se le agrega
#  mas widgets).Esto actualiza el ancho y alto de la ventana en caso de crecer.

#  Obtenemos el largo y  ancho de la pantalla
wtotal = root.winfo_screenwidth()
htotal = root.winfo_screenheight()
#  Guardamos el largo y alto de la ventana
wventana = 900
hventana = 300

#  Aplicamos la siguiente formula para calcular donde debería posicionarse
pwidth = round(wtotal/2-wventana/2)
pheight = round(htotal/2-hventana/2)

#  Se lo aplicamos a la geometría de la ventana
root.geometry(str(wventana)+"x"+str(hventana)+"+"+str(pwidth)+"+"+str(pheight))

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Eliezer, prueba con lo siguiente:

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()
ancho_ventana = 900
alto_ventana = 300

x_ventana = root.winfo_screenwidth() // 2 - ancho_ventana // 2
y_ventana = root.winfo_screenheight() // 2 - alto_ventana // 2

posicion = str(ancho_ventana) + "x" + str(alto_ventana) + "+" + str(x_ventana) + "+" + str(y_ventana)
root.geometry(posicion)

root.resizable(0,0)
root.title("Ventana de ejemplo")


root.mainloop()
```

Las variables **ancho_ventana** y **alto_ventana** se inicializan con las dimensiones que quieres que tenga tu ventana.

Luego, obtienes el ancho de la pantalla con **root.winfo_screenwidth()** y lo divides en dos, obteniendo sólo la parte entera, a lo que le restas la mitad del ancho de tu ventana. Lo mismo aplica para el alto, pero usando **root.winfo_screenheight()**.

Luego concatenas los datos para formar la cadena que espera `geometry`, en la variable **posicion**.